# MVVMCross iOS custom visibility converter not being called

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, valueconverter

I have a visibility converter for lists that functions perfectly on Android, but I cannot get the Convert method to be called in iOS.

```
public class ListVisibilityConverter : MvxBaseVisibilityValueConverter<IList>
{
    protected override MvxVisibility Convert(IList value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var inverse = false;
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            inverse = (bool)parameter;
        }

        var listHasEntries = (value != null) && value.Count > 0;

        if (inverse)
        {
            return listHasEntries ? MvxVisibility.Collapsed : MvxVisibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return listHasEntries ? MvxVisibility.Visible : MvxVisibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

I use the converter in a binding within the ViewDidLoad of a ViewController...

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<AddFriendsFromContactsViewController, AddFriendsFromContactsViewModel>();
set.Bind(collectionView).For("Visibility").To(vm => vm.SectionedCollection).WithConversion("ListVisibility", true);
set.Bind(noContactsFoundLabel).For("Visibility").To(vm => vm.SectionedCollection).WithConversion("ListVisibility", false);
set.Apply();
```

In Setup.cs I've confirmed the converter is being found with the following code...

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance()
{
    base.InitializeLastChance();
    var registry = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxValueConverterLookup>();
    var f = registry.Find(BindingStrings.ListVisibility);
    Mvx.Trace("Custom converter was found : {0}", f != null);
}
```

Comment: Just confirming that the `MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility` NuGet package is install in the your iOS project? Have you also tried clean/uninstall the app and rebuild/deploy? Is there any warnings/errors in the console output?

Comment: I've done a clean and uninstall, followed by a rebuild and deploy. Didn't resolve the problem. I am getting the following error in console - "MvxBind: Warning:  19.80 Failed to create target binding for binding Visibility for SectionedCollection". SectionedCollection derives from ObservableCollection.

Comment: I forgot to mention I also have the proper NuGet package installed.

Comment: Are you adding your assembly to the ValueConverters assemblies? Do you have the VisibilityPluginBootstrap file inside the Bootstrap folder in your platform project?

Comment: Overriding ValueConverterAssemblies in the Setup of the iOS project and manually adding the value converter solved the issue, nmilcoff. I don't understand why I had to manually do this in iOS, and not in Android, but I'm happy it's working. Please feel free to add an answer, and I'll mark it as correct (Otherwise I can add one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding ValueConverterAssemblies in the Setup of the iOS project and manually adding the value converter solved the issue.

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> ValueConverterAssemblies
{
    get
    {
        var assemblies = base.ValueConverterAssemblies;
        var valueConverterAssemblies = assemblies as Assembly[] ?? assemblies.ToArray();
        valueConverterAssemblies.ToList().Add(typeof(ListVisibilityConverter).Assembly);
        return valueConverterAssemblies;
    }
}
```